# Payment Success Page AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, payment

What's the correct AngularJS way to do this:

I have a page that accepts some user info and payment (via Stripe).

Upon success of the payment, I need to display the user a message to say it's been accepted.

Do I combine both views in the same partial (I suspect not), and then display one depending on the status of some scope variable, i.e. `$scope.paymentAccepted`.

```
<form ng-if='!paymentAccepted'>
    ...
</form>

<div id='paymentSuccess' ng-if='paymentAccepted'>
    <p>Your payment has been accepted</p>
</div>
```

or do I direct the user to another location using the `$location` service provider and then use a separate view and controller from there (I suspect this is the way).

Call this being fussy, but I want to stop users accessing my payment page directly which is why I am tempted to do this the first way.

What is the correct way of dealing with this?

Comment: Sounds like you want [to build a wizard](http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/angularjs-multi-step-form-using-ui-router) or [use a wizard module](https://github.com/mgonto/angular-wizard).

Comment: What you have above is pretty much a correct way to do it. Both ways are actually fine since I'm assuming this is a single page application.

Comment: The first method using `ng-if`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use ui-router you could have a child state of your payment state that isn't URL addressable.  You then just need to inject $state to your controller and transition to the relevant state on successful completion of payment, e.g. `$state.go('home.payment.success')`.

Edit: you'd actually reference the child state as `$state.go('.success')` assuming you were transitioning from the parent ('home.payment' in this example).